# Show-Hide divs using jquery in a dropdown But Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

When Form is Blank or i take new from for input something then Div is working. and html like

```
<select name="product" class="span4" id="product">
<option value="4">Article</option>
<option value="1">Product</option>
<option value="2">Movie Trailers</option>
<option value="3">Landing Page</option>
</select>

<div class="1 box"> Select Div 1</div>
<div class="2 box"> Select Div 2</div>
<div class="3 box"> Select Div 3</div>
<div class="4 box"> Select Div 4</div>
```

JavaScript: is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.box').hide();
  $('#product').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
 });
});
```

But When i go to edit article or product this not working and selected="selected" a category from DB. thin don't show div default which selected div

```
<select name="product" class="span4" id="product">
<option value="4">Article</option>
<option value="1">Product</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Movie Trailers</option>
<option value="3">Landing Page</option>
</select>
```

[image: Image Screen Short here]

I need both of Function Selected & without selected function. Would you like help me :)

Comment: code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/u920pvx1/ very hard to understand what you are asking for though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is you need to display element associated with value at the time of page load, just trigger the change event right after you bind the change event handler.

```
$('#product').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
 }).change(); // trigger change so the code inside change handler runs and displays correct eleemnt
```

Another syntax for same thing:

```
$('#product').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
 }).trigger('change');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u920pvx1/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Put your code for Change Function Out Side of Ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.box').hide();
});

 $('#product').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
 });
```

Comment: why would you do that? What if code is in head? Element won't exist when it executes

Comment: and the code outside will execute immediately , so if it precedes the html `$('#product')` will return no matches

Answer (score 0):

Simply show the box on document.ready like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.box').hide();
 $('.' + $('#product').val()).show();

  $('#product').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
 });
});
```